# What does the addSubview method look like?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, methods

I'm aware of it's function and how to use the addSubview method.

What would like to know is what the method looks like, the code used in that method it self.. and if someone could point me to the right direction in finding this out for my self next time.

I assume I could find it in the Developer Documentation, and I found the method, and what it does (which I already know) but I'd like to see sample code, if possible. Thanks =]

Comment: Why do you want to know the implementation details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation code is not publicly available, iOS is not open source. The closest you can get is the header file but that only declares the interface, which doesn't give you anything you can't get from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using the AppDelegate class from the "Empty Application" new project template:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // create label to add to UIView
    UILabel * label1 = [[UILabel] alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 100)];
    label1.text = @"Hello World";

    // create view to add to UIWindow
    UIView * view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    [view1 addSubview:label1];
    [label1 release];

    // create window to display
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    [self.window addSubview:view1];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [view1  release];

    return(YES);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code which you've displayed is a step by step process that creates the view and makes it show up on my screen. 

What I'm asking is , you see how you used the 'addSubview' method on self.window, I'd like to know how the 'addSubview' method it self looks like. -(void)addSubview; 

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you trying to override -(void)addSubview;?  If so, why do you want to override addSubview?

Comment: I actually do not, but yeah, now you're getting what I'm asking for :). 


I'm just curious, I just really want to know how it works. 

Um, to be less of a bother, is there a way to find this out on my own the next time? 

TIA.

Comment: I do not know how it works, but I could make a few guesses.  I'm not sure how you would go about definitively answering your question without seeing the source for the UIView class.